# PHP Multiple Logical Operator

Tags: php, json, logical-operators

Trying to figure out the best way to do this.
I have a PHP function that checks if something is true or not, and if it is, returns some JSON data.

The issue I'm having is that either one can return the data if the other is null, or both are true.

This is what I've tried:

```
if( $logic_type === true && $description== 'null' ){
    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );
}

if( $description === true && $logic_type == 'null' ){
    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );
}

if($description=== true && $logic_type === true ){
    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );
}
```

That seems to be way too long in the tooth.
So I tried:

```
if( $logic_type === true && $description== 'null' || $description === true && $logic_type == 'null' || $description=== true && $logic_type === true ){
    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );
}
```

But that only works if the last condition is met.

Comment: use brackets `($logic_type === true && $description== 'null') || (...) || (...)`

Comment: Still only returns if the last condition is met

Comment: Is the value literally the text "null" is it just `null`?

Comment: it's literally "null", comes from a javascript variable.

Comment: do you mean empty() or literal 'null' string?

Comment: Is there any possible value other than those 2?

Comment: no other possiblities

Comment: holy smokes... I'm dumb today. I was using the wrong variable... one of those days. $desciption and $logic_type right, but the variables being set to null were completely different.

Comment: happens, and that means it is time for your next coffee.. :)

Comment: Note that since only those are the only two possibilities, you can actually turn this into 2 conditions other than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parentheses for grouping your conditions

Quote from [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

> Use of parentheses, even when not strictly necessary, can often
>   increase readability of the code by making grouping explicit rather
>   than relying on the implicit operator precedence and associativity.

Try

```
if( ($logic_type === true && $description== 'null') || ($description === true && $logic_type == 'null') || ($description=== true && $logic_type === true) ){

    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose `$logic_type === true && $description== 'null' ||....` in the brackets because you are using `&&` and  `||`. Use the code below

```
if( ($logic_type === true && $description== 'null') || ($description === true && $logic_type == 'null') || ($description=== true && $logic_type === true ))
{
    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the perfect example of using an **exculsive or** (*A XOR B*). Which means either *A* or *B*, but not both. In your case you want either `$logic_type` to be null, or  `$description` to be null, but not both to be null. That or they both would be true. So we can simplify the expression to this, using a bit-wise XOR:

```
if( ($logic_type === 'null' ^ $description === 'null') || 
    ($logic_type === true && $description === true) )
{
    return json_encode( self::returnDataArray( $return_arrs ) );
}
```

Note that will only be if the only possible values for `$logic_type` and `$description` where either: `true` or `'null'`.